# Classifier - Acurracy with no class labels in testing set

Tags: python, classification, decision-tree

I want to make a decision tree classifier to predict the 'target' values (either 'made' or 'missed') in my testing set, and then calculate the accuracy of the classifier.

Header:
location,w,final_margin,shot_number,period,game_clock,shot_clock, dribbles,touch_time,shot_dist,pts_type,close_def_dist, target

Here is a section of the training set:

H,W,13,3,1,399,11.1,0,3.7,0.5,2,1,missed
A,L,-12,6,2,369,6.8,0,3.2,16.3,2,5.9,made
A,L,-4,2,2,449,24,1,1.6,4.9,2,1.5,missed
A,W,12,7,3,436,16.1,0,1.1,20.2,2,5,missed
A,W,4,16,4,253,14,5,5.5,8.1,2,3,missed
A,L,-19,12,3,359,6.6,2,3.6,7.3,2,2.8,made

part of the testing set:

H,W,12,16,3,161,11,5,4.6,6.5,2,2.3
H,W,4,3,1,343,15.3,0,0.7,3.1,2,2.7
A,L,-27,2,1,318,15.6,0,1,24.5,3,5
A,L,-6,5,2,253,16.7,7,7.9,3,2,1.1
A,W,2,4,1,365,12.8,1,2.8,4.3,2,2.3

I got this method for calculating accuracy:

```
def accuracy_metric(actual, predicted):
    correct = 0
    for i in range(len(actual)):
        if actual[i] == predicted[i]:
            correct += 1
    return correct / float(len(actual)) * 100.0
```

As you can see I have no actual values/class labels in the testing set, so how can I calculate the accuracy of the classifier after predicting class labels for the testing set?

Comment: You know what, you cant calculate the accuracy like that .Try splitting the training set you have into test set and train set then find the accuracy.. To find the accuracy having predicted target without actual target is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just cant - the whole concept of accuracy testing is to compare predicted values with actual values. If one of the two are missing, computing such a metric is inherently impossible.

What you want to do is split the data that already has labels into a training and testing section, and then you can compute accuracy metrics.

you might want to check out `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` if you are not writing your own splitter.

Comment: okay, I thoght so, but was confused because we got an assignment to predict values for the given test set, but I will just split the training set then. Thank you :)